# marking text in richtexbox

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a problem, I want to somehow mark text in my richtextbox. I tried to change font between adding content to richtextbox (below is code, but it works only on first text).

```
Font bolded = new Font("Georgia", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
Font normal = new Font("Georgia", 14, FontStyle.Regular);

logBox.Font = bolded;
logBox.Text += "Number of elements: " + dir.GetLength(0) + 
Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
logBox.Font = normal;
```

So, can I change anything to mark my text (bolding it would be the best), and If I can't do it on richtextbox is there any other way? (my app writes a lot to this item)

Edit: I'm targetting Windows Forms Application.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Also:  __Never__ change the Text property! __Only__ modify the SelectionXXX properties and/or the SelectedText after setting the selection via SelectionStart and SelectionLength! .property directly!!

Comment: I'm targeting Windows Forms Application, also could you provide an example of Selection or Selected Text usage, because I don't understand microsoft examples. @TaW

Comment: `richTextBox1.SelectionStart = i1; 
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = i2;
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = colorfore;
richTextBox1.SelectionFont= bolded;`